Reframing Collatz Conjecture as a property of meromorphic functions
I was wondering if it is known that the 3n+1 Collatz conjecture could be reframed as a statement about the set of solutions to a particular equation formulated as the sum of residues.  This is something that my office mate in graduate school and I played around with, but didn't get very far.
The Collatz recursion is

If $i\equiv 0\mod 2$, $f(i)=\frac{i}{2}$.
If $i\equiv 1\mod 4$, $f(i)=\frac{3i+1}{4}$.
If $i\equiv 3\mod 4$, $f(i)=\frac{3i+1}{2}$.

This form of the recursion ensures that $i = 1$ is a fixed point.  Now, introduce complex-valued functions that encode this recursion through the exponents in its Taylor expansion, where:
$f_0(x,y)=x+x^3y+x^5y^2+\dotsc=x\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{2j}y^j = \frac{x}{1-x^2y}$
$f_1(x,y)=1+x^4y^3+x^{8}y^6+\dotsc=\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{4j}y^{3j} = \frac{1}{1-x^4y^3}$
$f_3(x,y)=x^2y^4+x^6y^{10}+x^{10}y^{16}+\dotsc=x^2y^4\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{4j}y^{6j} = \frac{x^2y^4}{1-x^4y^6}$
Here, the power of $x$ is the initial integer minus 1, while the power of $y$ is the integer it is sent to by Collatz minus 1.  For example, the second term of $f_1(x,y)$ states that $4+1 = 5$ is sent to $3+1=4$ under Collatz recursion.
Now, with $f(x,y)=f_0(x,y)+f_1(x,y)+f_3(x,y)$, the twice-iterated Collatz recursion $f^2(x,y)$ can be accomplished through the contour integral
$
f^2(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{dz}{z}\, f(x,1/z)\, f(z,y)
$
where $C$ is the unit circle and we assume that $|x|,|y|<1$.  This process can be repeated, generating the expression for the $n+1$ iterated Collatz recursion from the $n$ recursion via
$
f^{n+1}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{dz}{z}\, f(x,1/z)\, f^n(z,y)
$
In this expression, only the function $f(x,1/z) / z$ has poles on the unit disc and so this can conveniently be expressed as a sum over residues.  Then, the Collatz conjecture can be stated as
$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x,y) = \frac{1}{1-x}
$
through whose Taylor expansion all integers are sent to 1.
The Collatz conjecture can also be formulated in terms of functions that remain stationaly under the recursion.  That is, consider a stationary function $g(x,y)$ such that
$
g(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{dz}{z}\, f(x,1/z)\, g(z,y)\,.
$
$g(x,y)$ has no poles in $x$ on the unit disc (excluding its boundary, for $|y|<1$), so this can be evaluated with the residue theorem.  Summing over all 10 residues of the Collatz kernel, the stationary function satisfies:
\begin{align}\label{ressum}
g(x,y)&=x\,g(x^2,y)+\frac{g(x^{4/3},y)+g((-1)^{2/3}x^{4/3},y)+g(-(-1)^{1/3}x^{4/3},y)}{3}\\
&\hspace{1cm}+\frac{g(x^{2/3},y)+g(-x^{2/3},y)}{6x^{2/3}}+(-1)^{2/3}\,\frac{g((-1)^{1/3}x^{2/3},y)+g(-(-1)^{1/3}x^{2/3},y)}{6x^{2/3}}\nonumber\\
&\hspace{1cm}-(-1)^{1/3}\,\frac{g((-1)^{2/3}x^{2/3},y)+g(-(-1)^{2/3}x^{2/3},y)}{6x^{2/3}}\,.\nonumber
\end{align}
The Collatz conjecture is then equivalent to there being a unique solution to this equation, where
\begin{align}
g(x,y) = \frac{1}{1-x},
\end{align}
and assuming that $g(x,y)$ has the appropriate form of the Taylor expansion.
I have only played around with this formulation a little bit, but haven't gained any further insight.  Does anyone know if such an approach has been studied elsewhere?

Hm, it's over my head at the moment. Can you consider negative integers for the Collatz-transformation and say something about the existence of cycles in the negatives? (Or is perhaps this case obvious/excluded somehow by your ansatz and I overlooked it?)

Hmm, I haven't thought about negative integer recursion much.  But perhaps there is a way to do it through an expansion about infinity on the complex plane, as a sort of inverse of positive integer recursion that is manifest in an expansion about 0.

Well, in principle one can express that "negative integers" by changing the transformation rule to $3x-1$ instead of the  $3x+1$ and then use again the positive integers for this. Is this perhaps an easier transformation?

Ahh, yes, this formulation is easily modified to any recursion relation on the integers.  For the 3x-1 rule, the stationary function formula is superficially not too different, but we know in that case that there are non-trivial cycles that do not reach 1.  So, what about the sum of residues of the 3x-1 rule allows for cycles, while 3x+1 perhaps does not?  I do not know.

What exactly do you mean by appropriate form of the Taylor expansion? Writing $g(x,y)=a_0(y)+a_1(y)x+a_2(y)x^2+...$, your functional equation subsequently gives $a_1(y)=a_0(y)$, $a_2(y)=a_4(y)$, $a_3(y)=a_1(y)$, $a_4(y)=a_3(y)$, $a_5(y)=a_2(y)$, $a_6(y)=a_{10}(y)$, $a_7(y)=a_3(y)$, etc. Thus if you multiply everything by any function of $y$ you get another solution.

Indeed, I didn't specify this clearly.  Because the residue formula is linear in g, you can always transform $g(x,y)\to v(y)g(x,y)$ where $v(y)$ is some function of $y$, to find another solution.  By "unique" in the statement of the Collatz conjecture, I mean unique up to homogeneous functional multiplication like this.

So then is not this a proof? If $g(x,y)=a_0(y)+a_1(y)x+a_2(y)x^2+...$ then $xg(x^2,y)=a_0(y)x+a_1(y)x^3+a_2(y)x^5+...$, $\frac{g(x^{4/3},y)+g((-1)^{2/3}x^{4/3},y)+g(-(-1)^{1/3}x^{4/3},y)}{3}=a_0(y)+a_3(y)x^4+a_6(y)x^8+a_9(y)x^{12}+...$, and $\frac{g(x^{2/3},y)+g(-x^{2/3},y)}{6x^{2/3}}+(-1)^{2/3}\frac{g((-1)^{1/3}x^{2/3},y)+g(-(-1)^{1/3}x^{2/3},y)}{6x^{2/3}}-(-1)^{1/3}\frac{g((-1)^{2/3}x^{2/3},y)+g(-(-1)^{2/3}x^{2/3},y)}{6x^{2/3}}=a_4(y)x^2+a_{10}(y)x^6+a_{16}(y)x^{10}+a_{22}(y)x^{14}+...$, and one then just equates coefficients, no?

Well, yes, but to "prove" the Collatz conjecture with that approach requires evaluating an infinite number of coefficients...I suspect that there is a way to solve this equation without Taylor expansion about 0, which correspondingly would not require evaluating an infinite number of terms.  However, I don't know how to do that.

Well, in a sense this infinite set of equations is very simple and explicit, it is $a_{2k+1}=a_k$, $a_{4k-2}=a_{6k-2}$, $a_{4k}=a_{3k}$ for all $k$. So your equation can be reduced to three simpler equations. For example, the first of these three is $\frac{g(x)-g(-x)}2=xg(x^2)$

The third is $\frac{g(x^3)+g(ix^3)+g(-x^3)+g(-ix^3)}4=\frac{g(x^4)+g((-1)^{2/3}x^4)+g((-1)^{4/3}x^4)}3$

and the second is$$3x^2(g(x^3)-g(ix^3)+g(-x^3)-g(-ix^3))=2(g(x^2)+(-1)^{2/3}g((-1)^{1/3}x^2)+(-1)^{4/3}g((-1)^{2/3}x^2)+g(-x^2)+(-1)^{2/3}g((-1)^{4/3}x^2)+(-1)^{4/3}g((-1)^{5/3}x^2))$$

Ahh, very cool!  I had not made this connection before.  Do these expressions simplify their solution?  Or, conversely, do they simplify what their solution cannot be?  Perhaps if one had a sufficently general parametrized form for a solution (not just Taylor expansion), then something could be said about functional forms that are inconsistent.

Well idk. At any rate I would start with the first one to look which restrictions does it impose on $g$, and then move on to add the third and the second.

The first constraint, $g(x)-g(-x) = 2x g(x^2)$, is satisfied by the series $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{m 2^n-1}$, where $m$ is an odd positive integer.  This is a lacunary function, and is essentially something sometimes called the Fredholm series.  One can then take linear combinations of this form with different values of $m$ and insert it into the other fixed-point equations.  Perhaps functions satisfying these equations that are not $1/(1-x)$ are necessarily lacunary?

Any solution for the first constraint (at least in the class of Taylor series) has form
$a_0f(x)+a_1x^2f(x^3)+a_2x^4f(x^5)+a_3x^6f(x^7)+a_4x^8f(x^9)+...+a_kx^{2k}f(x^{2k+1})+...$, where $f(x):=1+x+x^3+x^7+x^{15}+x^{31}+...$

Actually, the "only" thing that needs to be proved now is that this functional relationship forbids the function $g(x)$ from having any zeros on the unit disk.  A fixed function corresponding to some non-trivial cycle would have a Taylor expansion in $x$ that starts at some term $x^n$, for $n>0$.  Therefore, if $g(x)$ cannot have zeroes on the unit disk, such a possible fixed function is forbidden.

This is gonna seem cryptic but you need to think about the numbers $4$ and $-\frac13$, and specifically symmetries between them and what happens if you set them equivalent to each other. I wonder whether this simplifies if you adjust your taylor series to around those two points instead of around zero.

Yes, indeed cryptic!  Do you mean expansion of the Collatz recursion fixed function $g(x)$?
